# Foundation 6 Framework / Columns in Accordion

Tags: html, css, frame

I'm trying to get a grid layout in an accordion item.
My markup is like:

=> class accordion

=> class accordion-item
 => class accordion-content

When I'm trying to put a  inside of content and then some div's with different sizes (i.e. small-3, small-3, small-3, small-3) all these div's are in a new row instead side by side ..

---

DIV

DIV

DIV

DIV

instead of

DIV    DIV    DIV    DIV

---

Has someone an idea or a small example-code? or generally: is it possible to do the grid inside of an accordion?

Kind regards and thanks in advance.